# Some tasks fail without logs in airflow 2.2.3

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm using Airflow 2.2.3 and recently ran into a problem. The task becomes in the failed status but does not leave behind any log, no traces of execution on the worker. That is, there is no external_executor_id in flowers, which, meanwhile, is in Task Instance Details in Airflow.

The problem is not constant and sometimes everything works, sometimes not. and, what is more strange, the task is executed with an error and leaves behind a log only for some runs. For example:

```
ls /opt/airflow/logs/daily_talents_dag/processing_file.run_notebook_processing_file/2023-07-25T08:45:00+00:00
1.log  3.log  4.log
```

Logging and containers are configured correctly because many other tasks function correctly, the log gets where it needs to be and is displayed.

What's happening? How to fix it?

A manual restart usually works correctly.

Comment: Airflow version 2.2.3 is about 2 years old. I strongly recommend upgrading to a newer version for both additional features and lots of bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

This seems most likely to be a [zombie issue](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/tasks.html#zombie-undead-tasks), which are tasks that have, for some reason, lost connection with the Airflow database. In 2.2.3, zombies are handled in the [dag processing manager](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.2.3/airflow/dag_processing/manager.py#L1052), so I recommend reviewing those logs.

Zombies can be caused for a fairly wide variety of reasons, but one of the most likely is the worker running out of memory, so I recommend reviewing whether the worker ran out of memory.

Comment: I noticed that in the launch history, problematic tasks have the wrong hostname.
When creating docker containers again, the invalid hostname does not change, and sometimes they try to send a task to it.
Where can this hostname be stored? Maybe it's some kind of cache?
reference to a non-existent worker explains all the problems. I've tried deleting all docker volumes related to redis, but that didn't work.